# What is the use of Patch? Why we want to apply the patches? how to apply the patches?

Tags: magento2

Can anyone explain me briefly

1. Use of Patch?
2. Why do we want to apply the patches?

Thanks,

Comment: Go through this docs, this may be useful https://www.atwix.com/magento/security-patches-why/

Answer (score 0):

You can run command like this

```
git apply MAGEPatch-20191196.patch
```

or

```
patch -p1 < MDVA-14172_EE_2.3.1_COMPOSER_v1.patch
```

Comment: Am asking Magento2, how  can  we do that?

Comment: It's for magento2

Comment: How we know whether the patch is applied or not?

Comment: After applying patch you can check in core file, is it updated as given changes in patch file or not.

Answer (score 0):

1) Every patch is a package of modified core files that aims at fixing certain security issues that were discovered in Magento.

2) It is necesary to apply the patch. Without applying patch there is high possibility of hackers to gain access to your store’s admin panel and hijack your store.

Comment: where i can get the patch file?

Comment: You can check here.. You need check for which version patches is provided and what fix has been done..